# Bash - Edit structuraled text

Tags: bash, shell

I want to edit this text.

```
StringTable resource
{
    Entry _strings
    [ 

    //CUSTOM UI
        { String _name = "CCIconChartTip";          String _text = "Icon Chart for Colonial Charter."; }
        { String _name = "CCIconChart";             String _text = "Icon Chart"; }
.
.
.
    ]
}
```

To show only one word(or sentence) which is in "", how do I write codes?
Below codes are my codes but, they are not working.

```
while true
do
    ((string_num++))
    ori_string=$(sed -n '/string_num/p' $path)

    mid=${ori_string%\"} #To cut a line started with " From behind
    ori=${mid##\"} #To cut a line ended with "

    echo "Original : $ori"
    echo "Translate : "
    read -r trans
    if [ "$trans" -eq "p" ] # To skip
    then
        continue
    elif [ "$trans" -eq "q" ] # To quit
    then
        break
    fi
    sed 'string_nums/ori/trans/g' path
done
```

Sorry for my bad English skill.

Input and output

```
$ sh Banished_translator.sh
Enter a file name
NewLimitStringTable.rsc
Skip to b. Quit to q
Original :
Translate :
```

Nothing outputing.

Comment: Can you give an example with input and output? Something like: When I enter `CCIconChartTip` I want to see the translation `Icon Chart for Colonial Charter.` (if that is what you want)

Comment: Please run your code and show us the current output.

Comment: I update my post with output.
As you can see, It doesn't output anything.

Comment: A question title should be *specific to the individual problem*, so that as much as possible someone can tell if its answers will help them with *their own* problem from just the title and summary blurb. Right now, this is quite broad -- this title would apply no hundreds of other questions on the site just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look to closely at your code, but I saw at least two instances of calling `sed` in a way that you probably did not intended:

1. `sed -n '/string_num/p' $path`

   This looks for the literal string `string_num` in the file given by `$path`.  You probably meant `sed -n "/$string_num/p" "$path"` (print lines containing `$string_num`) or `sed -n "${string_num}p" "$path"` (print line number `$string_num`).  Also note the quoting of `$path`.
2. `sed 'string_nums/ori/trans/g' path`

   This should have given you an error about an "unterminated `s` command". I'm guessing that you meant `sed "${string_num}s/$ori/$trans/g" "$path"` here, but that would not work if `$ori` contained characters that are interpreted as regular expression symbols, or if `$trans` contained similarly special characters.

Also, your tests with `-eq` should have generated errors since `-eq` is used to test equality of *integers*.  String comparisons within `[ ... ]` are done with `=`.

---

Assuming there are no *nested or escaped* `"`, and that all such strings are never broken over several lines.

Using the data that you have provided:

```
$ grep -oE '"[^"]+"' file
"CCIconChartTip"
"Icon Chart for Colonial Charter."
"CCIconChart"
"Icon Chart"
```

The expression `"[^"]+"` will match a `"` followed by at least one non-`"` character and another `"`. Note that this is a fairly simplistic matching, but it works with your provided data.

Further assuming that every odd line of this output is the "original" text that you refer to and that you want to read translated versions of these from the user and replace them in the original file. We can create a tab-delimited list of pairs:

```
$ grep -oE '"[^"]+"' file | paste - -
"CCIconChartTip"        "Icon Chart for Colonial Charter."
"CCIconChart"   "Icon Chart"
```

... and then read that to create our question for the user:

```
exec 3<&1
grep -oE '"[^"]+"' file |  paste - - |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r short long; do
    printf 'Original:\t%s (%s)\n' "$long" "$short"
    read -u 3 -rp  'Enter translation (p=pass, q=quit): ' trans
    [ "$trans" = "p" ] && continue
    [ "$trans" = "q" ] && break

    sed -i "s/$long/\"$trans\"/" file    # fixme
done
```

We need to do some juggling with filedescriptors here so that the internal `read` does not read from the output of `paste`.

The `sed` suffers from the same issue as in your code (if you correct it), in that any characters of `$long` or `$trans` that happens to be a regular expression character will mess up the call to `sed`.

The general approach would work though, if you found a better way of actually updating the original file with the text provided by the translator.

IMHO, it may be less error prone to actually provide the original file to the author and let them edit it with a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, you have many syntax errors in your code, and some weird logic.  To verify your syntax, you can use https://www.shellcheck.net/.

I did the best with the limited information provided, but here is my take on your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
read -p "Enter a file name: " path

# validate file existance
if [ ! -f $path ]
then
    echo "ERROR: file $path does not exist.  Aborting."
    exit 1
fi

# Counter to know which line the script is currently reading
string_num=0
# Number of lines in file $path
numberoflines=$(wc -l $path | awk '{print $1}')

echo ""
echo "Press 'p' or ENTER to pass, 'q' to quit."

# Read line per line up to the last line in the $path file
while [ $string_num -le $numberoflines ]
do
    (( string_num++ ))

    # Read the line number $string_num
    ori_string=$(sed -n "${string_num}p" $path)

    # First section of text enclosed in ""
    ori=$(echo $ori_string | cut -d'"' -f2)
    # Second section of text enclosed in ""
    mid=$(echo $ori_string | cut -d'"' -f4)

    echo ""
    echo "Original: $ori"
    read -p "Translation: " trans

    if [ "$trans" == "p" ] # To skip
    then
        continue
    fi

    if [ "$trans" == "q" ] # To quit
    then
        break
    fi

    # If the $trans value is == $ori, then output the value of $mid
    if [ "$trans" == "$ori" ] && [ "$ori" != "" ]
    then
        echo "    RESULT: $mid"
    fi
done
```

- I added a check to ensure the input file exists, avoids errors.
- I removed the `while true`.  There is no need to look forever after you reached the end of the file.
- When you compare numbers in `if` statements, you use -eq, -le, -lt, ...  To compare text, you `==` or `!=`.

Anyway, try it out and adapt as required.